# How to handle double quotes in string before XPath evaluation?

Tags: php, string, xpath, quotes, xpath-1.0

In the function below, when string in $keyword contains double quotes, it does create a *"Warning: DOMXPath::evaluate(): Invalid expression"*:

```
$keyword = 'This is "causing" an error';
$xPath->evaluate('boolean(//img[contains(@alt, "'.$keyword.'")])');
```

What should I do to prep `$keyword` for the evaluate xpath expression?

The full function code:

```
$keyword = trim(strtolower(rseo_getKeyword($post)));

function sx_function($heading, $post){
    $content = $post->post_content;
    if($content=="" || !class_exists('DOMDocument')) return false;
    $keyword = trim(strtolower(rseo_getKeyword($post)));
    @$dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML(strtolower($post->post_content));
    $xPath = new DOMXPath(@$dom);
    switch ($heading)
        {
        case "img-alt": return $xPath->evaluate('boolean(//img[contains(@alt, "'.$keyword.'")])');
        default: return $xPath->evaluate('boolean(/html/body//'.$heading.'[contains(.,"'.$keyword.'")])');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

PHP has Xpath 1.0, if you have a string with double and single quotes, a workaround is using the Xpath `concat()` function. A helper function can decide when to use what. Example/Usage:

```
xpath_string('I lowe "double" quotes.');
// xpath:    'I lowe "double" quotes.'

xpath_string('It\'s my life.');
// xpath:    "It's my life."

xpath_string('Say: "Hello\'sen".');
// xpath:    concat('Say: "Hello', "'", "'sen".')
```

The helper function:

```
/**
 * xpath string handling xpath 1.0 "quoting"
 *
 * @param string $input
 * @return string
 */
function xpath_string($input) {

    if (false === strpos($input, "'")) {
        return "'$input'";
    }

    if (false === strpos($input, '"')) {
        return "\"$input\"";
    }

    return "concat('" . strtr($input, array("'" => '\', "\'", \'')) . "')";
}
```

Comment: This is a rad solution.

Answer (score 4):

To escape the string delimiters in [XPath 2.0 string literals](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#prod-xpath-StringLiteral) you need to replace each single delimiter by two, so `"` needs to be replaced by `""`:

> ```
> [74]      StringLiteral      ::=      ('"' (EscapeQuot | [^"])* '"') | ("'" (EscapeApos | [^'])* "'") /* ws: explicit */
> [75]      EscapeQuot     ::=      '""'
> [76]      EscapeApos     ::=      "''"
> ```

I’m not sure if there already is a function to do that but you can use this function:

```
function xpath_quote($str, $quotation='"') {
    if ($quotation != '"' && $quotation != "'") return false;
    return str_replace($quotation, $quotation.$quotation, $str);
}
```

And the usage:

```
'boolean(/html/body//'.$heading.'[contains(.,"'.xpath_quote($keyword).'")])'
```

Comment: `DOMXPath` is Xpath 1.0, you linked the Xpath 2.0 specs.

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming PHP8.4.0 will have DOMXPath::quote() (which I authored https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/13456 ), so as of PHP8.4.0:

```php
        case "img-alt": return $xPath->evaluate('boolean(//img[contains(@alt, '.$xPath->quote($keyword).')])');
        default: return $xPath->evaluate('boolean(/html/body//'.$heading.'[contains(.,'.$xPath->quote($keyword).')])');
```

and prior to PHP8.4.0, you can use

```php
function UserlandDOMXPathQuote(string $string): string {
{
    if (false === \strpos($string, '\'')) {
        return '\'' . $string . '\'';
    }
    if (false === \strpos($string, '"')) {
        return '"' . $string . '"';
    }
    // if the string contains both single and double quotes, construct an
    // expression that concatenates all non-double-quote substrings with
    // the quotes, e.g.:
    //  'foo'"bar => concat("'foo'", '"bar")
    $sb = [];
    while ($string !== '') {
        $bytesUntilSingleQuote = \strcspn($string, '\'');
        $bytesUntilDoubleQuote = \strcspn($string, '"');
        $quoteMethod = ($bytesUntilSingleQuote > $bytesUntilDoubleQuote) ? "'" : '"';
        $bytesUntilQuote = \max($bytesUntilSingleQuote, $bytesUntilDoubleQuote);
        $sb[] = $quoteMethod . \substr($string, 0, $bytesUntilQuote) . $quoteMethod;
        $string = \substr($string, $bytesUntilQuote);
    }
    $sb = \implode(',', $sb);
    return 'concat(' . $sb . ')';
}
```