# Searching XML data in PHP

Tags: php, html, xml

Hello everyone I know to do this search with MySQL using `LIKE '"%% $ _POST [" txtbuscar "]%%"'`, I am now performing in XML. I need to come up with an input txtbuscar.

The script below I have managed to list and page, and search for the most important word, but I believe that is something, but is not working, could you help me please?

#### XML

```
<listaccts>
    <acct>
        <disklimit>100M</disklimit>
        <diskused>100M</diskused>
        <domain>dominio.com.br</domain>
        <ip>123.124.125.126</ip>
        <user>Fulano</user>
        <plan>Plano1</plan>
    </acct>
    <acct>
        <disklimit>200M</disklimit>
        <diskused>200</diskused>
        <domain>dominio.com.br</domain>
        <ip>123.124.125.126</ip>
        <user>Fulano2</user>
        <plan>Plano2</plan>
    </acct>
</listaccts>
```

#### PHP

```
$accounts = $xmlapi->listaccts();
$xml = simplexml_load_string($accounts);

if ($_POST["txtBuscar"] == "ligar") {

    $busc = $_POST["buscarURL"];

    foreach ($xml->xpath('//acct') as $acct) {

        $minhaArray = $xml->xpath('//user[.>$busc]');

        $minhaArray = array();
        foreach ($xml->acct as $acct) {
            $minhaArray[] = array(
                    'domain' => (string)$acct->domain,
                    'user' => (string)$acct->user,
                    'ip' => (string)$acct->ip,
                    'disklimit' => (string)$acct->disklimit,
                    'diskused' => (string)$acct->diskused,
                    'plan' => (string)$acct->plan);
        }
    }
```

#### HTML

```
<form id="formBuscaClienteUrl" name="formBuscaClienteUrl" method="post" action="" class="sky-form" onsubmit="return false">
    <input name="txtBuscar" type="hidden" value="ligar" />
    <script language="javascript">document.formBuscaClienteUrl.buscarURL.focus();</script>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td width="95%" style="padding-left:10px;">
                <input name="buscarURL" type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td width="5%"><button style="padding-left:10px;" type="submit" onclick="buscar('formBuscaClienteUrl')" class="button" >Localizar</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

//======================== that's OK ==============

I made some adjustments, is now up, in case anyone wants. Thanks

$busc=$_POST["buscarURL"];

```
$expression = sprintf("/*/acct[contains(user, '$busc')]", $_POST["buscarURL"]);
$result = $xml->xpath($expression);

$minhaArray = array();
foreach($result as $account){
    $minhaArray[] = array(
        'domain'=>(string)$account->domain,
        'user'=>(string)$account->user,
        'ip'=>(string)$account->ip,
        'disklimit'=>(string)$account->disklimit,
        'diskused'=>(string)$account->diskused,
        'plan'=>(string)$account->plan,

    );

}
```

Comment: First of all you need to do proper input validation and encoding, see [How to handle double quotes in string before XPath evaluation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4820067/367456). Like your SQL is prone to SQL injection, your XPATH is prone to XPATH injection. Next to that you're picking up too  much out of the blue. Reading through http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic should give you a more safe introduction on how things work in simplexml incl. the very xpath basics.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to query from an XML document, most easy often is to do via Xpath (as you already thought about), the `LIKE` you know from SQL is perhaps in your case comparable with `contains()` in Xpath:

```
$listaccts = new SimpleXMLElement($accounts);
$txtBuscar = 'lano';

$expression = sprintf('/*/acct[contains(user, %s)]', xpath_string($txtBuscar));
$result = $listaccts->xpath($expression);

foreach($result as $account) {
    printf("User..: %s\nDomain: %s\n", $account->user, $account->domain);
}
```

Output with your example set:

```
User..: Fulano
Domain: dominio.com.br
User..: Fulano2
Domain: example.com.br
```

Note: Like in SQL where you need to take care of SQL injection, I take care as well about xpath injection by properly encoding the search value as string (this perhaps misses an UTF-8 sanitizer in a real-life example when you fetch from `$_POST` and you don't have your system already configured to sanitize the input generally).