# SimpleXML and php - get a node that contains text that matches another node

Tags: php, simplexml, xmlnode

I am trying to display the text content of a Node, if the content of that node matches another node (sibling). Here is the XML:

```
<MemberId>
    <BillingInfo>
        <Details>
            <Line NUMBER="0">
                <ChargeDate>20140605</ChargeDate>
                <DueDate>20140605</DueDate>
                <TrackingNumber>PR DED</TrackingNumber>
                <Description>Account payroll deduction</Description>
                <RevCode>SJ1550</RevCode>
                <RevDesc>ACCOUNT PAYROLL DEDUCTION</RevDesc>
                <SalesAmount>-11.77</SalesAmount>
                <ServiceCharge>0.00</ServiceCharge>
                <GST>0.00</GST>
                <PST>0.00</PST>
                <Othertaxes>0.00</Othertaxes>
                <Total>-11.77</Total>
                <ChitCode>PR DED</ChitCode>
                <ChitDate>20140605</ChitDate>
            </Line>

            <Line NUMBER="1">
                <ChargeDate>20140605</ChargeDate>
                <DueDate>20140605</DueDate>
                <TrackingNumber>03128862</TrackingNumber>
                <Description>Mountain Mkt Sales</Description>
                <RevCode>SJ1553</RevCode>
                <RevDesc>MOUNTAIN MKT SALES</RevDesc>
                <SalesAmount>8.99</SalesAmount>
                <ServiceCharge>0.00</ServiceCharge>
                <GST>0.00</GST>
                <PST>0.61</PST>
                <Othertaxes>0.00</Othertaxes>
                <Total>9.60</Total>
                <ChitCode>03128862</ChitCode>
                <ChitDate>20140605</ChitDate>
            </Line>
        </Details>
    </BillingInfo>
    <Chits>
    <Chit>
    <Code>03128862</Code>
    <Body><![CDATA[
        Member#: 0ECHER
        Name: *******
        Area:  *********
        Server: JEANNEANE
        Chit#: 03128862
        Date:  June 5 2014
        ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
        1       MINGUA BEEF JER            8.99
        ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
        Sub-Total                          8.99


        TAX                                0.61
        ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
        Chit Total                         9.60



        MEMBER CHARGE                     -9.60
    ]]></Body>
    </Chit>
    </Chits>
</MemberId>
```

I am successfully displaying each ChitCode and ChitDate, because they are in the Line[@number] Node. I want to display the Body node that contains the text "Chit#: XXXXXX" where xxxxxx matches Line->ChitCode. Here is my php, it displays the Body, but it displays the first Body for all the line items:

```
<?php 
    foreach($Chitquery as $Chit) 
    {
        foreach($Linequery as $Line)
        {
            echo "<label class='collapse' for='".$Line->ChitCode."-".$Line->ChitDate."'>".$Line->Description."</label>
            <input id='".$Line->ChitCode."-".$Line->ChitDate."' type='checkbox'>
            <div>"; 
            // Creates hide - show link for each Description item
            // Start getting the matching Chit Code from Chit/Body                          

            if ($Chit->Code = $Line->ChitCode)
            {
                echo $Chit->Body."</div>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo " ".$Line->ChitCode."</div>";
            } // End If
        } //End  foreach Linequery
    } // End foreach Chitquery
?>
```

It's the echo $Chit->Body.""; that I need help with, I want to display the Body that contains the value of $Line->ChitCode.

Oh yeah, and the lines are repeating weird, due to improper placement of 'foreach' statements!
[image: screenshot of lists]
Help! Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I have changed my php code and now I have the hide-show divs working, with no duplicates, but I get 'array' instead of $ChitBody. I cannot figure out how to find the Body node that contains the $Line->ChitCode in $ChitBody = $member->xpath('Chits/Chit/Body[text()="'.$Line->ChitCode.'"] ');

```
<?php 
                        foreach($Linequery as $Line) { 
                        $ChitCode = $member->Chits->Chit->Code;
                        $ChitBody = $member->xpath('Chits/Chit/Body[text()="'.$Line->ChitCode.'"] ');
                        echo "<label class='collapse' for='".$Line->ChitCode."-".$Line->ChitDate."'>".$Line->Description."</label>
                         <input id='".$Line->ChitCode."-".$Line->ChitDate."' type='checkbox'>"; // Creates hide - show link for each Description item
                        // Start getting the matching Chit Code from Chit/Body                          
                            if ($ChitCode = $Line->ChitCode) {
                            echo "<div>Code: ".$ChitCode."<br>".$ChitBody."</div>";
                            } else {
                            echo "<div>".$Line->ChitCode."</div>";
                            } // End If
                        } //End  foreachLinequery
                     ?>
```

[image]

Comment: You have $Chit->Code = $Line->ChitCode in if statement. Try to change it to $Chit->Code == $Line->ChitCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely looking for xpath to query you document.

for example to iterate over the lines - I don't fully understand why you do it the way you do it, but here is how I understand it to go over the lines (text-only output):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);

foreach ($xml->xpath('//Details/Line') as $line)
{
    printf("#%d: %s\n", $line['NUMBER'], $line->Description);            
}
```

which gives:

```
#0: Account payroll deduction
#1: Mountain Mkt Sales
```

I guess you see how this works in general. So now for getting chit based on `$line->ChitCode`, which is I think actually the more interesting part for you. It also better illustrates the benefits of xpath:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//Details/Line') as $line)
{
    printf("#%d: [%s] %s\n", $line['NUMBER'], $line->ChitCode, $line->Description);

    $query  = sprintf("//Chits/Chit[Code = '%s']/Body", $line->ChitCode);
    $result = $xml->xpath($query);

    if ($result) {
        $chit = $result[0];
        echo $chit;
    } else {
        echo ' -- no chit found -- ';
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

This time the query contains the condition to look for the number (in case you want to make this save, [escape the string properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12810818/367456) ([more info](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/mitigating-xpath-injection-attacks-in-php/))), it basically creates the following two xpath queries:

```
//Chits/Chit[Code = 'PR DED']/Body

//Chits/Chit[Code = '03128862']/Body
```

I again guess you can imagine what those mean. In case such a `<Body>` element is found, the code above outputs it. And this is how the result looks like:

```
#0: [PR DED] Account payroll deduction
 -- no chit found -- 
#1: [03128862] Mountain Mkt Sales

        Member#: 0ECHER
        Name: *******
        Area:  *********
        Server: JEANNEANE
        Chit#: 03128862
        Date:  June 5 2014
        ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
        1       MINGUA BEEF JER            8.99
        ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
        Sub-Total                          8.99


        TAX                                0.61
        ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
        Chit Total                         9.60



        MEMBER CHARGE                     -9.60
```

I hope this gives you enough insight to get started with it. [`xpath()` is just a method on **SimpleXMLElement**](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath) so you can combine this as well with your code which I didn't copy just to have the example smaller (same reason why I use plain text output here, would work equally with HTMl but would bloat the example).

---

Addition by OP:

**THAT WORKED GREAT!!**

I adapted your code to this, and it worked perfectly:

```
foreach ($Linequery as $Line) {
    $LineChitCode = $Line->ChitCode;
    $ChitBody     = sprintf("//Chits/Chit[Code = '%s']/Body", $LineChitCode);
    $CBresult     = $member->xpath($ChitBody);
    echo "<label class='collapse' for='" . $Line->ChitCode . "-" . $Line->ChitDate . "'>" . $Line->Description . "</label>
                             <input id='" . $Line->ChitCode . "-" . $Line->ChitDate . "' type='checkbox'>"; // Creates hide - show link for each Description item
    // Start getting the matching Chit Code from Chit/Body                            
    if ($CBresult) {
        $chit = $CBresult[0];
        echo "<div>Code: " . $LineChitCode . "<br>" . $chit . "</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div>" . $Line->ChitCode . "</div>";
    }
}
```

Thank you, you saved me from 3 days of trying to figure this out!!

Comment: @CharlieTrig: You can also look for siblings with xpath, but this way was more straight forward. Just FYI :)

Answer (score 0):

you  may  use  if ($Chit->Code == $Line->ChitCode) instead of   if ($Chit->Code = $Line->ChitCode)

Comment: That didn't work. Still have the repeats, and does not display the Body match to $Line->ChitCode